# HtmlInputRadioButton Checked property not working in Chrome

Tags: c#, jquery, google-chrome

An html input of type radio is set using jQuery's .prop() function. Then whether it is selected or not is being checked in aspx.cs(C#) using .Checked property.

html :

`<input id="AmountRadio" enableviewstate="true" runat="server" type="radio" value="Amount" onclick="ChangeVisibility('a')" />`

In ChangeVisibility function the property is set :

`var amountRadio = $('#AmountRadio');
amountRadio.prop('checked', true);`

In C# :

`if(AmountRadio.Checked)`

When the application is run in IE then the Checked property in C# works properly. But when run in Chrome the Checked property always returns false.
Anyone has an idea on this one?

Comment: What is `amountRadio`?

Comment: It is the ID of the input ctrl. Edited question.

Comment: try this `amountRadio.attr('checked', true);` or amountRadio.attr('checked', 'checked');

Comment: Sorry that didnt work. I also tried `amountRadio.prop('checked', 'checked');` and `amountRadio.prop({checked: true});` . Once the jQuery LoC is executed, the checked property of the radio button is seen to be true. But in code behind the difference is still there when run in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately used hidden field to store the value of the radio button to get the functionality to work. Would like to know the real solution though.